# How to check Tag added event in Coral UI 3

Tags: aem

I want to capture the tag added and removed event on select of a tag field in Coral UI 3. I have added this in a clientlib which has category of `cq.authoring.dialog.all`.

```
(function($, $document) {
    $document.on("dialog-ready", function() {
        $('[data-fieldname="./cq:tags"]').on('itemadded', function(ev, value) {
            console.log("Tag added");
        });
    });
})($, $(document));
```

The `sling:resourceType` of tag field is Coral UI 3 specific: `cq/gui/components/coral/common/form/tagfield`

But this event is no captured. If I change tag field resourcetype to old Touch UI specific `sling:resourceType` as `cq/gui/components/common/tagspicker` then it works.

**How do I capture event in Coral UI 3 tag field?**

Comment: Which AEM version specifically is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `/libs/cq/gui/components/coral/common/form/tagfield/render.jsp` (at least in AEM 6.4), you'll see it renders the following HTML structure:

```
<foundation-autocomplete>
    <coral-overlay></coral-overlay>
    <coral-taglist>
    ...
    </coral-taglist>
</foundation-autocomplete>
```

`foundation-autocomplete`'s documentation can be found here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/clientlibs/foundation/js/autocomplete/index.html

But what you are interested in is the `coral-taglist` the documentation for that is here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.TagList.html

the `items` in a coral-taglist are of type `Coral.Collection` whose docs are here: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-4/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/coral-ui/coralui3/Coral.Collection.html#Coral.Collection:events

so you can do something like:

```
document.querySelector(<coral-taglist element selector>).on('coral-collection:add', function () {
  // handle add
})

document.querySelector(<coral-taglist element selector>).on('coral-collection:remove', function () {
  // handle remove
})
```

Comment: You are right, but I had to remove items , as follows :  document.querySelector("coral-taglist[name='./cq:tags']").on('coral-collection:add', function(ev, value) {
             var items = document.querySelector("coral-taglist[name='./cq:tags']").items.getAll();
        });

Comment: I have not actually tested it but that’s odd since the documentation describe it how I described it. In any case, glad it worked!

Comment: I’ve updated the answer with what worked for you, ie. removing “items”